# OpenEdge Progress not finding custom DLL

Tags: c#, dll, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm having some issues while loading my custom DLL to OpenEdge Enviroment.

I've already copied my DLL to an PROPATH value and imported the DLL inside ProAsmRef.exe (The DLL is in the same folder as ProAsmRef and assemblies.xml)

The problem is, when I try to load my custom file inside a procedure, it sends me this current error:

```
**Unknown table name PCControl. (200)
```

I've already imported the DLL on my definition block with:

```
USING PCControl.*.
```

My DLL depends on another DLL (System.DirectoryServices.dll) but is already on assemblies.xml.

I can't figure it out why PCControl isn't importing, because I already have another two DLL's and they are working just fine...

Thanks for the help!

My DLL Code:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace PCControl{

public class PCC{

public static string AzureLogin(string user, string password) {

        string status;

        try {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://AUTOEXPR.COM", user, password) {
                AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure,
                Username = user,
                Password = password
            };

            DirectorySearcher _searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            _searcher.Filter = "(objectclass=user)";
            SearchResult _sr = _searcher.FindOne();
            string? _name = _sr.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();

            status = "SUCCESS - User " + user + " has logged in.";

        } catch (System.Exception e) {
            status = "ERROR - While logging in: " + e.ToString();

        }

        return status;
    }
}
}
```

My XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<references xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <assembly name="ClassADT, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <assembly name="ClassOPC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <assembly name="PCControl, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <assembly name="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</references>
```

My login.p (resumed):

```
    &ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _PROCEDURE Login C-Win 
PROCEDURE Login :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 
    DEF VAR lSuccess AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
 
    lSuccess = PCControl.PCC:AzureLogin("arorap1", "12345").
 
    MESSAGE lSuccess
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO
        TITLE "ok".
 
 
END PROCEDURE.
 
/* _UIB-CODE-BLOCK-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME
```

This issue is not related to my code into DLL... I've added the function in my co-worker's DLL and it works perfectly:

```
USING ClassADT.*.

DEFINE VARIABLE LSuccess AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
    IF AVAIL usr_param AND usr_param.usr_ativo EQ TRUE THEN
        lSuccess = ClassADT.MyAdt:MyLogin(txtUser:SCREEN-VALUE, txtPassword:SCREEN-VALUE).
```

Comment: Please share your ABL procedure and the assemblies.xml file contents.

Comment: @RaphaelFrei Please implement these into your original post instead of commenting them. Also, [it's much more helpful to provide a minimal, reproducible example than using a Pastebin link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339451/8156202)

Comment: Hi! I've resumed my code on the post... it has more than 300 lines in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I've managed to fix it by copying the assemblies.xml from bin folder to root folder.

Somehow, Progress wasn't reading the XML from the PROPATH folders... I've added the assemblies to DLC117 and it's working all the functions from the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use an intermediate class variable?

```
def var ologin as PCControl.PCC no-undo.

ologin = new PCcontrol.PCC().
ologin:AzureLogin( 'user', 'pass' ).
```

I *think* only OpenEdge static classes can be used directly as you are doing.

Comment: Defining ologin as PCControl it gives me the error: 
`Invalid specified datatype (5638)`

And when I change it to char the error is: 
`Impossible to find class or interface PCControl.PCC. (12886)`

Comment: I've added another section in the post... I can use my function directly from my co-worker's DLL... the issue is only when I try to import my own

Comment: ok... is your dll blocked by any chance? https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000051521

Comment: I’ve commented the answer… it wasn’t reading the assemblies file from the propath folder… it started reading from the dlc117